# The Clipboard returns null if I use Excel Interop's range.CopyPicture

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, clipboard

I'm trying to make a program that can create menus and then make pictures from them. This is my first time using these "Interops" and so far, I managed to make them work. I have tried different solutions to my problem, but none of them worked for me.

This is what I have so far:

```
        Range re = worksheet.Range["A1:U37"];
        re.CopyPicture(XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);     
        IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        Image image = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
        image.Save("image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

To my understanding, this is supposed to copy the selected range from excel, into the Clipboard and then retrieve it from there. But for me it always throws an exception at the save part, saying "**System.NullReferenceException, image was null"**

EDIT: File opening and Image making code

```
        string path = Path.GetFullPath("just_an_excel.xlsx");
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path, false, true);
        Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        worksheet.Copy();
        worksheet = excel.Workbooks[2].Sheets[1];
        excel.Workbooks[1].Close();
        excel.Visible = true;

        Range re = worksheet.Range["A1:A7"];
        re.CopyPicture(XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);
        IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        Image image = (Image)data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, true);
        image.Save("image.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: The question seems interesting. Can you put a bit more code in it, thus it is a [mcve], and someone can copy and paste it exactly to reproduce the error?

Comment: The Windows Clipboard behaves in different ways depending on what kind of data it's storing, and where it came from.  It would be a good idea to research the differences before you continue.  The short story is that it will in some cases hold data (in the case of an image, it would be stored as a bitmap) or else it can store a pointer to a specific file or section of memory.  It's not as simple as "taking" what's on the clipboard. In some cases it would need to be rendered (for example, copying a range of Excel cells to another application.)

Comment: Here's a link to some information about [**Windows Clipboard**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648709.aspx) from MSDN.   Also [**Using the Clipboard**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard). These links refer to multiple coding languages but the basic premise is the same.